# In Eclipse statusbar is there a way to include a new statusfield (say the file's line delimiters )?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, statusbar

Iam writing an eclipse plugin with a customized text editor. The status bar contibutor iam using is is the default one. and these fields displayed are
[image: Standard Eclipse statusbar]

i believe they are because of the following in `org.eclipse.ui.part.EditorActionBarContributor`

```
/**
 * The status fields to be set to the editor
 * @since 3.0
 */
private final static StatusFieldDef[] STATUS_FIELD_DEFS= {
    new StatusFieldDef(ITextEditorActionConstants.STATUS_CATEGORY_FIND_FIELD, null, false, EditorMessages.Editor_FindIncremental_reverse_name.length() + 15),
    new StatusFieldDef(ITextEditorActionConstants.STATUS_CATEGORY_ELEMENT_STATE, null, true, StatusLineContributionItem.DEFAULT_WIDTH_IN_CHARS + 1),
    new StatusFieldDef(ITextEditorActionConstants.STATUS_CATEGORY_INPUT_MODE, ITextEditorActionDefinitionIds.TOGGLE_OVERWRITE, true, StatusLineContributionItem.DEFAULT_WIDTH_IN_CHARS),
    new StatusFieldDef(ITextEditorActionConstants.STATUS_CATEGORY_INPUT_POSITION, ITextEditorActionConstants.GOTO_LINE, true, StatusLineContributionItem.DEFAULT_WIDTH_IN_CHARS)
};
```

my question is how to add a new status field for linedelimiter type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define you own editor action bar contributor which extends `BasicTextEditorActionContributor` to get the standard status fields.

Override `contributeToStatusLine` and add new status line contribution items for your extra items:

```
@Override
public void contributeToStatusLine(IStatusLineManager statusLineManager) {
  super.contributeToStatusLine(statusLineManager);

  statusLineManager.add(item);
}
```

where `item` is a `StatusLineContributionItem` which you should create in the action bar contributor construtor:

```
item = new StatusLineContributionItem("id", true, width in characters);
```

In the `setActiveEditor` method you should set the action for the item and tell the editor about the status field:

```
@Override
public void setActiveEditor(IEditorPart part) {

  // TODO check this is your editor

  item.setActionHandler(... get action handler from editor...);

  ITextEditorExtension extension = (ITextEditorExtension)part;
  extension.setStatusField(item, "id");
}
```

In your main editor code extending `TextEditor` you can then call

```
IStatusField statusField = getStatusField("id");

statusField.setText("text");
statusField.setImage(image);
```

Comment: it worked!!, thank you very much. however the field gets pdated only when i call a method to update it when file is gettng changed. and not at the time when the editor receives focus...iam trying that. but any help is appreciated.